# How to get value from onclick through Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get value from onclick but the code below gives me empty list. What am I doing wrong?

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
from re import findall,search

class myParser(HTMLParser):
    sites = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'div':
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == 'onclick':

                    self.sites.append(attr[1])

    def get_sites(self):
        return self.sites

website = urlopen('https://www.classicshorts.com/stories/')
html = website.read()
content = html.decode()
url = findall('"openStory\(\'/stories/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\'\)"',content)
print(url)

Parser = myParser()
link = Parser.feed(content)
sites = Parser.get_sites()
```

But this code giving me empty list.

URL I am trying to get is

```
<div onclick="openStory('/stories/aos.html')" class="storylisting">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;">An Affair of State</span>--Guy de Maupassant (1850-1893)
            </div>
```

IMPORTANT: All the links have same class = 'storylisting' if that gives any hint

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't the problem, your page is. Print the "content" and see yourself. It just doesn't have any onclick="openStory('...')" in there. In any case, testing your regex with the code below (adding just the ( ) so it only picks the actual link) works fine:

```
from re import findall,search

content = r"""<div onclick="openStory('/stories/aos.html')" class="storylisting">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">An Affair of State</span>--Guy de Maupassant (1850-1893)
</div>"""

url = findall('"openStory\(\'(/stories/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)\'\)"',content)
print(url)
```

Edit: adding a piece of code that parses all the stories URLS

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from re import findall

base_url = "https://www.classicshorts.com"
link_pages = ["/abc/a-d.html", "/abc/e-h.html", "/abc/i-m.html", "/abc/n-s.html", "/abc/t-z.html"]

for page in link_pages:
    content = urlopen(base_url + page).read().decode()
    for story_url in findall('"openStory\(\'(/stories/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)\'\)"',content):
        print(base_url + story_url)
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but how to get link from all the onclick elements of the website? I mean not only aos.html but many other stories?

Comment: I've added a full working example, with the "stories by abc" links hardcoded into it.